# How can I get it all in one embed?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a command to see all members with a specific role in that server. But with what I have now I get an embed for every single member that has that role. But I want it all in one embed, but how?

```py
@bot.command(name='members', aliases=['Members'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def members(ctx,*args):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    role_name = (' '.join(args))
    role_id = server.roles[0]
    for role in server.roles:
        if role_name == role.name:
            role_id = role
            break
    else:
        await ctx.send("Role doesn't exist")
        return
    for member in server.members:
        if role_id in member.roles:
            embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Members of {role}",description=f"{member.display_name} - {member.id}", color=0xfcf8f8)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here are few things to keep in mind**

1. Instead of looping through `Guild.roles` you can use [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get).
2. Instead of looping through `Guild.members` and checking if member has the role, we have [`Role.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.members) which returns a list of members having that role.
3. Instead of a for loop, [`join()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) can be used and code can be minimized.

```py
@bot.command(name='members', aliases=['Members'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def members(ctx,*args):
    name = " ".join(args)
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=name)
    if not role:
        return await ctx.send("Role not found")
    member_string = "\n".join([i.display_name + " - " + str(i.id) for i in role.members])
    e = discord.Embed(title=f"Members of {role.name}", description=member_string, color=0xfcf8f8)
    await ctx.send(embed=e)
```

Comment: And how do i make an extra embed if there is more than 2000 characters

Comment: check if `len(member_string) > 2000` then make another embed, in the 1st in description put `member_string[:1999]` and in second embed in description put `member_string[2000:]`

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing now is looping through each member and sending an embed if they have the role you want. As a result you're sending one embed for each member, rather than sending one embed containing all the information you want. One possible solution I wrote is to create a string that contains all the members and their information, then send that in one embed.

```py
member_string = ""

for member in server.members:
    if role_id in member.roles:
        member_string += "\nmember.display_name - member.id"
embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Members of {role}",description=member_string, color=0xfcf8f8)
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: And how do i make an extra embed if there is more than 2000 characters